# Ruby select with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{"green" => 1, "red" => 2, "blue" => 3}, {"green" => 4, "red" => 5, "blue" => 6}]
```

I want to select the hash in which either red, blue or green is equal to a certain number.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Ive tried using select three times but i was wondering if i could do this in one line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood You correctly.

```
arr = [{"green" => 1, "red" => 2, "blue" => 3}, {"green" => 4, "red" => 5, "blue" => 6}]
some_number = 1
arr.select { |el| el.any? {|k,v| v == some_number} }
```

Improved version:

```
arr.select { |el| a.has_value?(some_number) }
```

Version if there could be more keys that don't need to be tested (yellow in example):

```
arr = [{"green" => 1, "red" => 2, "blue" => 3, "yellow" => 5}, {"green" => 4, "red" => 5, "blue" => 6, "yellow" => 3}]
some_number = 1
fields_to_check = ["red", "green", "blue" ]
arr.select { |el| fields_to_check.any? {|color| el[color] == some_number } }
```

Comment: I added improved version.

Comment: Note that this can break if any other colors are added to the hashes, but their values should not be included by the any?-logic

Comment: Agree, added version that takes it into account.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [`Hash#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) to get an array of the values associated with the keys you're interested in:

```
arr = [{"green" => 1, "red" => 2, "blue" => 3}, {"green" => 4, "red" => 5, "blue" => 6}]
arr.select { |h| h.values_at("red", "green", "blue").include? 1 }
```

Comment: Great solution! As the original question only want THE hash, I would use the find method instead of select. No array, little shorter.

Comment: Good solution. I still get surprised how many enumurable/hash/array methods are there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select a hash if any key's value is equal to `n`

```
 arr.select{|h| h.values.include? n}
```

To select if one of the specified key's value is equal to `n`

```
 arr.select{|h| h.select{|k,v| ("red","green","blue").include? k && v == n}
```

Comment: `.slice` is added by ActiveSupport and isn't available in plain ruby. Also, you'd have to `symbolize_keys!` on the hash before referring to the colours as symbols.